# Modification in one MultiValueMap affecting another

Tags: java, dictionary

I have two MultiValueMap in my class
Those are `MapA` and `MapB`. Two maps are equal. I have iterate Using `MapA` and Did some changes in `MapB`. But it is affecting the `MapA`. `MapA` is also changing. Why it happens.

**EDIT**

Simple Code

```
MultiValueMap myMap = new MultiValueMap();
myMap.put("A", "1");
myMap.put("B", "2");

myMap.put("C", "3");

myMap.put("D", "4");

System.out.println("Mymap => "+myMap);
MultiValueMap sec = myMap;

if(myMap.containsKey("A"))
{
    sec.getCollection("A").clear();
    sec.put("A", "11");


}


System.out.println(myMap); // {D=[4], A=[11], B=[2], C=[3]}
System.out.println(sec); // {D=[4], A=[11], B=[2], C=[3]}
```

Comment: Show us some code. Normally, this shouldn't happen but it can if you make a mistake.

Comment: You have 2000+ reputation. I expect you to know how SO works. Please show your code.

Comment: Can you post some code. I think you are using the same object references in both the maps.

Answer (score 0):

This -- almost certainly -- happens because the two maps contain references to the same objects. When you modify the object, it automatically changes in both maps.

Comment: Yes. It have same objects. But, How can i overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

`MultiValueMap sec = myMap;` doesn't make a copy; it makes `sec` refer to the exact same `MultiValueMap` as `myMap`.

Comment: How can i resolve this problem.... I want to change `sec` by iterating `mymap`. How to do this?